# What are some practical applications of inductive-inductive types?

Tags: soft-question, dependent-type

By "practical applications" I mean in usual programming/industry. I am particularly interested in cases where the inductive-inductive types cannot be easily replaced by inductive-recursive types.

One example that comes to mind is writing other programing languages. What are some others?

I would consider the following use of inductive-recursive types to be somewhat practical:

```
module _ (A : Set) (_#_ : A → A → Set) where
  data Dlist : Set
  Fresh : Dlist → A → Set

  data Dlist where
    nil : Dlist
    cons : (b : A) (u : Dlist) (b' : Fresh u b) → Dlist

  Fresh nil a = 
  Fresh (cons b u b') a = (b # a) × Fresh u a
```

(Though it's arguable if it's just easier to use plain inductive types with extra data.)

Comment: At the very least, if you don't want to turn off people and have them downvote you (llike I did), try to ask more positively: "*In addition* to such-and-such uses of inductive-inductive types, what *other* uses are there, especially ones that can have practical value?" Using derision quotes, prohibiting people from mentioning certain uses etc., that's not a good way to communicate.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the question. Please feel free to revert my changes if you dislike them.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Thanks for the changes, it was not my intention to ask negatively. I agree this is a much better way to ask, and will do so in the future.

Comment: (Also, my quotes were not meant to be used for derision, but to acknowledge that what is practical and what is not is fuzzy at best. In retrospective, I see now that my intended meaning was not clear at all. I apologize for any misunderstandings.)

Comment: I always assumed your question was well-meaning. Now it's my turn to apologize for making rather stern comments, I could have been more welcoming too.